# Simple jQuery question

Tags: jquery, html, css

check out http://social.allthingswebdesign.com. If you click the "Get Social" link, it pops out and when you move your mouse off of it, it goes back to where it started.

Now if you click the "Get Social" link, and when it pops out you click the "X" to close it, it goes too far in, and then pops out.

Check it out and you'll see what I mean. This seems like a very simple thing, but I'm having a serious brain fart and can't figure it out.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').prepend('<div id="social"><div id="outer"><span><img src="getSocial.png" alt="Get Social" />' +
                            '<ul id="icons"><li><img class="tiny" src="fb.png" alt="Facebook" /></li><li><img class="tiny" src="twit.png" alt="Twitter" /></li></ul>' +
                            '</span></div><div id="inner"><div id="innest"><ul><li>'+
                            '<img src="fb.png" alt="Facebook" /><a href="#">Find Us On Facebook</a>'+
                            '</li><li>'+
                            '<img src="twit.png" alt="Twitter" /><a href="#">Follow Us On Twitter</a>'+
                            '</li></ul><div id="close"><a id="closeB" href="#">X</a></div></div></div></div>');

        $('#social').live('hover', function() {
            var $lefty = $(this);
            $lefty.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft')) == -302 ? 
                -295 : -302
            }, 200);
        });

        $('#social').live('click', function() {
            var $lefty = $(this);
            $lefty.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
                (40 - $lefty.outerWidth()) : 0
            }, 200);
        });

        $('#closeB').live('click', function() {
            var $button = $(this).parent('#social');
            $button.stop().animate({
                marginLeft: parseInt($button.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
                -302 : 0
            }, 200);
        });

    });
```

Comment: FYI, it only seems to be happening in Chrome for me (works in Firefox)

Comment: It's not working in FF for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `closeB` just needs to set it to `-295` instead of `-302`.

```
$('#closeB').live('click', function() {
    var $button = $(this).parent('#social');
    $button.stop().animate({
        marginLeft: parseInt($button.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
        -295 : 0
    }, 200);
});
```

When I apply my own close button to the sliding box with the code above, it works fine.

---

You may want to do a CSS Reset to normalize some of your CSS across browsers. Since you're relying on the edge of the window, I'd guess this will be necessary.

Comment: doesn't work. Still goes too far back and then bounces back to normal.

Comment: @Catfish: Works perfectly for me, but then I had to prevent the event from bubbling since it seems that clicking anywhere on the box closes it. Do you have another click event on the box itself?

Comment: Yes I do actually, but if you click anywhere on the box, it closes fine and if you actually click on the X, it closes too far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code is working, because this line:

```
var $button = $(this).parent('#social');
```

returns a blank `$button`. You should use `closest()` instead of `parent`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/5qGZc/

**EDIT:**

First: `stopPropagation` of the `$('#closeB').live('click'...` event to prevent the `$('#social').live('click...` event handler to be called:

```
    $('#closeB').click(function(event) {
        var $button = $(this).closest('#social');
   -->  event.stopPropagation();  <--
        $button.stop().animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($button.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
            -302 : 0
        }, 200);
    });
```

Second: do not calculate the new position on `$('#social').live('click...` but use a fixed one (like in other handlers):

```
    $('#social').click(function() {
        var $lefty = $(this);
        $lefty.stop().animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($lefty.css('marginLeft')) == 0 ? 
        ->> -302 <--: 0
        }, 200);
    });
```

Third: Instead of using `live` you can just use `bind` or even shorter `click`.

**2nd EDIT:**
After closing the "Social" box, it is positioned as if it where hovered over. To prevent that, instead of playing with current margin, just use `event.type`:

```
    $('#social').live('hover', function(event) {
        var $lefty = $(this);
        $lefty.stop().animate({
        --> marginLeft: event.type == 'mouseenter' ? <--
            -295 : -302
        }, 200);
    });
```

because the current margin can be updated via a `click` handler and the original `hover` handler didn't notice about that.

Comment: your jsfiddle still pushes the green tab in too far when you click the X.